# I stuck in binomial probability (PMF) with parameter n & p

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I stuck in this example, but I have many trying

[image: this exercise its about random variable PMF to show many compute]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? From your picture it seems like you got most, if not all of it, though I can't make out some parts due to the small print.

Comment: I add now te other part, but I no sure its my result are corectly

Comment: From what I can make out, it seems like you used the moment generating function, that is a perfectly valid method.

Comment: Do you think its all process are good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to begin with the fact that  $$\sum_{k=0}^n \Pr[K = k] = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = (p+(1-p))^n = 1^n = 1.$$  We also need to observe the following identity: $$\begin{align*} \binom{k}{r} \binom{n}{k} &= \frac{k!}{r! \, (k-r)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{r! \, (k-r)! \, (n-k)!} \\ &= \frac{n! \, (n-r)!}{r! \, (n-r)! \, (k-r)! \, (n-k)!} = \binom{n}{r} \binom{n-r}{k-r},\end{align*}$$ where $0 \le r \le k \le n$, otherwise the LHS and RHS both equal zero.  Now for a fixed $r \ge 0$, define the random variable $$M_r = \binom{K}{r}.$$  Then $$\begin{align*} {\rm E}[M_r] &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{r} \Pr[K = k] \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{r}\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \\ &= \sum_{k=r}^n \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{k-r} p^r p^{k-r} (1-p)^{n-k} \\ &= \binom{n}{r} p^r \sum_{k=r}^n \binom{n-r}{k-r} p^{k-r} (1-p)^{n-k} \\ &= \binom{n}{r} p^r \sum_{k'=0}^{n-r} \binom{n-r}{k'} p^{k'} (1-p)^{(n-r)-k'} \\ &= \binom{n}{r} p^r,\end{align*}$$ where the last equality holds because the sum is simply the sum of a binomial PMF for $n' = n-r$ and therefore equals $1$.  But $$\begin{align*} {\rm E}[K(K-1)\ldots(K-r+1)] &= {\rm E}[r! \, M_r] = r! \, {\rm E}[M_r] = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!} p^r \\ &= n(n-1)\ldots(n-r+1) p^r. \end{align*}$$  This proves (a), (b), (c) as special cases for $r = 1, 2, 3$.  The final part is simply algebra, using the linearity of expectation.